# Search a HashMap in an ArrayList of HashMap

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of HashMap. I want to search a HashMap  in it but unable to find a way to achieve this. Please suggest me how it can be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Iterate over all `HashMap`s in an `ArrayList` and check one after another for key?

Comment: Do you want to search a single map in a list of maps? How would you recognize that single map you have to search?

Comment: Save it to a database and search it with SQL? Index it with Lucene and search for full text? Transform into a reverse-indexed red-black tree? Based on what you said, who knows...

Comment: Actually i have Two lists of map. i am moving map from first list to second. I don't want the duplicate map in second List. that's why i want to check weather the map exist in the list before adding.

Comment: i tried. but it didn't work as it returns true only if the two variables are referencing same objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to your question the way i understood it!

```
for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : yourArrayList)
    {
        // For each hashmap, iterate over it
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry  : hashMap.entrySet())
        {
           // Do something with your entrySet, for example get the key.
           String sListName = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
```

Your Hashmap might use other types, this one uses Strings.

Comment: It does not make sense to iterate entire list of you find the key in middle of list.

Answer (score 5):

See if this helps:

```
@Test
public void searchMap() {
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key1", "value1");
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key2", "value2");
    Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key3", "value3");
    listOfMaps.add(map1);
    listOfMaps.add(map2);
    listOfMaps.add(map3);

    String keyToSearch = "key2";
    for (Map<String, String> map : listOfMaps) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            if (keyToSearch.equals(key)) {
                System.out.println("Found : " + key + " / value : " + map.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
Object myObj;
Object myKey;
//Traverse the list
for(HashMap curMap : listOfMaps){
    //If this map has the object, that is the key doesn't return a null object
    if( (myObj = curMap.get(myKey)) != null) {
         //Stop traversing because we are done
         break;
    }
}
//Act on the object
if(myObj != null) {
  //TODO: Do your logic here
}
```

If you are looking to get the reference to the Map instead of the object (for whatever reason) same process applies, except you just store the reference to the map:

```
Map myMap;
Object myKey;
//Traverse the list
for(HashMap curMap : listOfMaps){
    //If this map has the object, that is the key doesn't return a null object
    if(curMap.get(myKey) != null) {
         //Store instance to the map
         myMap = curMap;
         //Stop traversing because we are done
         break;
    }
}
//Act on the map
if(myMap != null) {
  //TODO: Do your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below improved code for searching the key in a list of HashMap.

```
public static boolean searchInMap(String keyToSearch)
{
    boolean returnVal = false;
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key1", "value1");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key2", "value2");

    Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("key3", "value3");

    listOfMaps.add(map1);
    listOfMaps.add(map2);
    listOfMaps.add(map3);

    for (Map<String, String> map : listOfMaps)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(keyToSearch))
        {
            returnVal =true;
                break;
        }

    }
    return returnVal;

}
```

Comment: Pass the keys as an argument which need to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

The Efficient way i've used to search a hashmap in an arraylist without using loops. Since loop makes execution time longer

```
try{
int index = list.indexOf(map); // map is your map to find in ArrayList
if(index>=0){
HashMap<String, String> map = array_list.get(index);
// Here you can get your values
}
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
Log.i("HashMap","Not Found");
}
```

Comment: This is ridiculous, if I already have the map object, why do I need to get it from the list again?

Answer (score 0):

if you have an ArrayList like this one: **ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>**
and you want to compare one of the values inside the HashMap try this code.

I use it to compare settings of my alarm notifications.

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : AlarmList) {
  for (String key : map.keySet()) 
  {
      if (key.equals("SendungsID")) 
      {
         if(map.get(key).equals(alarmMap.get("AlarmID")))
         {
               //found this value in ArrayList
         } 
      }
   }
}
```